# Does this optimal control problem have a solution?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, control-theory, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

> Given a fixed $T > 0$ and the ODE $$\dot{x}(t) = a u(t)$$ where $x(t)$ is the state and $u(t)$ is the control input, find the optimal pair $(x^{\ast}(t), u^{\ast}(t))$
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\int^{T}_{0} \left( u^2(t) + x^2(t) \right) \, \mathrm d t\\ \text{subject to} & x(0)=1\\ & x(T)  \text{ is free}\\ & u(t) \in [0,1]\end{array}$$

If $a>0$, I can find the optimal pair. However, if $a<0$, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: The hint in the textbook says that "Try $u^{\ast}(t) \in (0,1)$ for all t".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to solve this problem by optimal control theory.

The Hamiltonian is $H=-(u^2+x^2)+pau$, thus $H^{\prime}_{u}=-2u+pu$.

$H$ is a concave function in $u$, so $u^{\ast}=\frac{pa}{2}$ is a candidate for optimality. Then we can get
$$u^{\ast}=\frac{1}{1+e^{2aT}}(e^{at}-e^{2aT}e^{-at})$$

It can be verified that $u^{\ast} \in(0,1)$ . So $u^{\ast}$ satisfied all conditions. We conclude that  $u^{\ast}$ is the optimal control.

Comment: when the variable $u$ is written in terms of $x'$ your Hamiltonian should be related to my Lagrangian via a Legendre transform. It worries me that we get different values for the optimal control. What is $p$? Also, see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67765/how-is-a-hamiltonian-constructed-from-a-lagrangian-with-a-legendre-transform